# How to derive the Sum of Square for Latin Square with repetition

Tags: self-study, sums-of-squares, latin-square

I am studying the Latin Square Design with `n` repetitions from https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat503/lesson/4/4.4

Let say we talk about the repetitions case 3 i.e. *we have different levels of both the row and the column factors*. I have 2 questions

- Why `DF` for row/column is $n \left(t-1 \right)$? SHould not it be $nt - 1$?
- How can I derive the Row/Column Sum of square?

Any hint/guidance would be very helpful.